# What is the purpose of the "Beautify" tool?

Tags: godus

Once you've got to the Primitive Age, you unlock a god power called **Beautify**. The in game detail for which states as follows;

[image]

Since you can already make your people settle anywhere you want using the totem to guide them, all this ability actually seems to do is make the ground shiny;

[image]

Am I missing something or is this tool pretty much specifically for cleaning up blighted land? Does the **Beautify** tool have any other uses?

Comment: Do you really need a reason to use it beyond making things shiny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides making the ground shiny and attractive to imaginary unicorns, its main purpose is the removal of blighted land. Blighted land slows your followers down and makes them sick, besides looking unappealing. As far as I know, it doesn't have any other uses.

Comment: Actually it will also change the behavior of your followers.  If you only beautify mountain villages, then God only likes/approves of them.  You can see the effects of your actions through the commandments when you increase in age.  Fairly hard to notice in the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I found out it revives burnt trees.

Useful if you accidentally burn down half your world after meticulously saving as many trees as possible...